# Conditional formatting for cells that contain words listed in another column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Column with rows of words where I want to highlight words that are used in other Columns. The other columns however contain sentences. Anyone knows how this is possible?
In this example Column A contains the words and the words should be highlighted if they are used in Sentences in all rows of Column B or C.

Column A:

1. Sausage
2. Wiener
3. Brat

Column B:

1. I like Sausage
2. I don't like Steaks

Column C:

1. I like Brat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`regexmatch`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en): create a conditional formatting rule with custom formula

```
=regexmatch(B1, join("|", filter($A:$A, len($A:$A))))
```

And apply it to the range B:C (or to another range; the cell given as B1 above must be the upper left corner of that range).

Here `filter($A:$A, len($A:$A))` takes the content of nonempty cells, and `join` creates a regular expression out of them, like Sausage|Wiener|Brat. Cells are highlighted if they match that regex. Some variations:

Include **word boundaries**, so that only whole words are matched:

```
=regexmatch(B1, "\b(" & join("|", filter($A:$A, len($A:$A))) & ")\b")
```

**Case-insensitive** matching with word boundaries:

```
=regexmatch(B1, "(?i)\b(" & join("|", filter($A:$A, len($A:$A))) & ")\b")
```

Comment: Not sure why but it doesn't seem to work for me. The words don't get highlighted. I created a conditional formatting rule with this custom formula and applied it to the range B:C, could I maybe share that spreadsheet with you?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, New Years Holidays. Here is the link, THX!! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ARDvwRJAPG4uXL-IyT4Qv3P0RQMFDj4OviM3GKK5Blg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Wtf suddenly it works :D many thanks! Just a short extra Question, I would love to have the items highlighted in Column A not in the other Columns. Is that possible as well?

Comment: If you give me a hint maybe I'd find it out on my own?

Comment: Fantastic.  Very helpful.  Have used this multiple times now.