# formatting formula Highlight all cells in a column of text strings sentences, that contain any of the phrases or keywords from another column in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, format, lookup

I have a list of sentences in column A. and a list of keywords and phrases in column B.
I need a conditional formatting formula or some other way of highlighting any of the sentences in column a that contain any of the exact phrases or keywords that are in column b.

**Column A For example..**

There is a sentence here

Example sentence flower stunning

boarding pass example text

sentence containing shabby chic

example large rock sentence

example text hardcore

examples sentence

some text here

**Column B For example....**

Pink

Black & White Flower

Stunning

Titanium Gold

Boarding Pass

Shabby Chic

Rock With You

Hardcore

Swirly

Fantastic Four

Adolescent

Keyring

Large Rock

My column A has over 100k sentences and column b has over 3000 phrases or keywords. Otherwise I would have gone to conditional formatting, text that contains, and highlight for each word individually.
I've spent hours googling with no luck. Below is the closest article I found but not quite what i need.

[Conditional formatting for cells that contain words listed in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023121/conditional-formatting-for-cells-that-contain-words-listed-in-another-column)

Even if there is a different way that is not highlighting them I'm open to that. I just need to identify every cell in column A that contains one of the words or phrases from column b

Comment: That article you linked appears to do what you asked. Why is it not sufficient?

Comment: Do you need to know which phrase(s) from Column B is matching Column A?

Comment: No i don't need to know which phrases match, the formula by JvdV works mostly,  it is highlighting the word "princess" in the sentence list if the word "prince" is in the keyword list for example but i think I can work with it, it certainly narrows it down much better for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you mean with an exact match, but the following might work when you want to see if any of the values in the 2nd column exist as a substring in the 1st one:

[image]

```
=SUM(COUNTIF($A1,"*"&$B$1:$B$13&"*"))
```

A much more stricter version could be to concatenate spaces on either side of the 1st and 2nd column. This will weigh more heavy on the calculation side of things though:

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$B$1:$B$13&" "," "&$A1&" ")))
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is 90% what i needed...the only issue is it is highlighting the word "princess" in the sentence list if the word "prince" is in the keyword list but i think I can work with it, it certainly narrows  it down much better for me, many thanks for your help!

Comment: Another issue is it highlights the sentence if it contains a partial match, so for example there is a sentence that says "Year Of The Dog" and in the keyword list I have a phrase that says "Family Dog" however, because that sentence contains "dog" it is highlighted, even though I'd only want "family Dog" highlighted if that makes sense.

Comment: The last comment makes no sense unfortunately and is also impossible @H-M. That is by definition not the reason why that sentence would be highlighted. The 1st problem is exactly the thing I mentioned at the top of the answer, or at least what I tried to warn you for. It would become a tad more difficult if you are looking for exact matches. Not impossible though, but it would require a different set of functions.

Comment: I'm not sure why that is happening then, but your solution still helped me narrow down over 100k sentences to around 6k so it has been very helpful thank you, and I can try and do the rest by eye at least which was impossible before. Have bought you a "drink" for your trouble. Thank you

Comment: @H-M, the "drink" is much appreciated! But a little pre-mature as I'm in the middel of trying to add a more strict and therefor hopefully better approach.

Comment: Oh brilliant, thank you very much! Will keep an eager eye.

Comment: @H-M, done..... If you have more questions about how to implement this then, you can find me also over [here](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jvdv-073152276/)

Comment: @H-M. Have you noticed the edited answer?

Comment: I did thank you, my task is now completed, thank you for your help!